# filter records within MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm new to replication process.

In one of Rails project it's necessary to share records of one table between two applications.

Let's say share records between first application DB `A` and second application DB `B`.
I decided to move that logic on DB level.

- Is is possible to configure `MySQL` replication in order to copy only particular records (e.g. records `where need_to_replicate_to_B_flag = true`)?
- Or I should find another way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on databases and/or tables only.  See the manual on binlog/replicate-do/ignore-db/table

The filtering can be before leaving the Master (`binlog-...`) or as it comes into the Slave (`replicate-...`).

The main intent of Replication is for the Slave to be an identical copy of the Master.  Your request is deviating quite far from that.

Comment: Rick, thank you for answer. I understand that replication is aimed to get identical copy. But this solution is the only one I see. Can you advice something more suitable?

Comment: Have those rows in a different database?

Comment: Have a flag in the table -- then have the `SELECTs` do the filtering?

Comment: Sorry, you need to add complexity to the application.

Comment: Rick, sorry I remove comment suddenly. Thank you for taking part in my problem and for saving my time. I will try to do it in application.